# "$.ajax is not a function", but only if call is placed inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

It's been a while since I've done web programming now, and managed to get myself into some trouble. Probably a trivial thing to solve for someone, but I've searched quite a bit online. All I can find are various way to solve the "$.ajax is not a function" problem by using the correct jQuery source. I've got that one figured out. What I'm wondering about is why does the ajax call work perfectly when not inside a javascript function? As soon as a put it in a function, I get the "$.ajax is not a function" problem. Here's my source:

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callback() {}
$(".dropdown-item").on("click", function () {
    // Does not work
    callAjax();
});

// Does not work if called from wherever
function callAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ajax", "Company")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: "myName" },
        success: callback
    });
}

// Does work (Same as above, just outside function)
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ajax", "Company")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: "myName" },
    success: callback
});
</script>
```

Comment: Most likely, you're including jquery twice, and the second version is a slim build.

Comment: Are you using wordpress?  I've seen at least one other question on the site that was the result of wordpress auto including a slim version of jQuery.

Comment: I've been very careful not to use the slim version (that's why I also included the first jQuery include at the top of the source code I posted). But many default files are being created when using the MVC template, so maybe it has been included some place I don't know of. I found a couple of places, where I switched them out, so thought that got fixed. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: As a test, do `console.log($.fn.jquery)` prior to the ajax call that is failing (inside the function.) That will confirm/deny whether or not you have a slim build.

Comment: @Pelle Fairly easy to F12 open your developer tools, go to the network tab, refresh the page, and look for requests for \*\*/\*jquery\*.js files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tells us that some script code later in the file is either:

1. Calling jQuery's `noConflict` function, which releases the `$` identifier, or
2. Including some script that overwrites the value in `$` (for instance: MooTools.js, Prototype.js, or even jQuery itself in its "slim" build)

You can solve it by wrapping your code in a function that uses its own `$`, like this:

```
(function($) {
    // ...your code here, can use `$` without worrying...
})(jQuery); // <==  Passes in `jQuery`, which is a synonym for `$`
```

Even if some later code calls `noConflict`, or even completely overwrites `$` (or even `jQuery`), that code will continue to work because it grabs the value of `jQuery` as of when it runs.

Comment: @Pelle - It's probably worth tracking down what it is that's overwriting `$` and dealing with it. If it's another copy of jQuery, for instance, it shouldn't be necessary. (If it's MooTools or PrototypeJS or something, some parts of the page may be using it -- which is unfortunate as loading *both* jQuery and another DOM lib makes the page fairly heavyweight...) Happy coding!