# TypeError: $.ajax is not a function , occurs only if $.ajax() is called inside a function (DJANGO)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856812/ajax-is-not-a-function-but-only-if-call-is-placed-inside-function) , but same error,
works outside a arrow or simple function.
code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
keyPressed = () => {
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: '/search/',
          data: {
            'search': 'hydroxi',
          },
          headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
          },
          success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: hello dear
please check if the script are loaded , you can check this from network section in your browser

Comment: Yes they are , ajax() works properly if placed  outside a function

Comment: can you send jQuery object as parameter to your function like this : `var keyPressed = ($) => { ....`  , when you call the function , add jQuery object as parameter like this : `keyPressed($);`

Comment: It sounds like `$` within the function does not refer to jQuery. What do you see in the console when you do `console.log($)` in the `keypressed` handler

Comment: yes i tried  keyPressed = ($) also ,but  then it shows - $ is undefined

Comment: **console.log($)** says  undefined

Comment: There's your problem then. However we can't help you further without seeing a more complete example of your JS.

Comment: there's no other JavaScript on this page , I've added all of it

Comment: ok, got the problem , i actually commented all import of js which included slim build jquery of bootsrrap using _{% comment %}  {% endcomment %}_ syntax, provided by Django extension in vscode, and this comment syntax didnt work, so above mentioned import was replaced by slim build jquery

Comment: try to replace $.ajax with jQuery.ajax